# Jquery file upload append images to list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I use Jquery File Upload plugin to upload images to cloud (Cloudinary). Cloudinary provide helper I can use to get those images from cloud. I want to use this helper to append images to list, but somehow images are out of the li (**see screenshot**) and I don't know why. I ran out of the ideas and need some help from you. Please suggest how else I can append images to li?

Below is how I do it:

```
  var preview = $('.uploaded_image ul').append('<li></li>');
   $.cloudinary.image(data.result.public_id, {format: data.result.format, width: 250, height: 135, crop: "fill"}).appendTo(preview);
```

([image: see screenshot])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `preview` is still referencing `.uploaded_image ul` instead of the new `<li></li>`, so you are basically appending the images to the `<ul>` instead.

Quick fix:

```
    // Change this:
    //var preview = $('.uploaded_image ul').append('<li></li>');
    // To this:
    var preview = $('<li></li>').appendTo('.uploaded_image ul');
```